# Changing text color of active menu item with CSS

Tags: css, joomla

I need your help with changing the text color of the active menu item on my website, using CSS.

(It's a Joomla website and I'm modifying the standard Gantry framework template to our needs).

Here is the CSS for the active menu item...

```
.gf-menu.l1 > li.active {
      background: none;
      color: #19D57E;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #19D57E;
      border-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-top: 1px;
    }
```

And here is the CSS for the passive menu items...

```
 .gf-menu .item {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 21px;
      color: #555555;
      padding: 4px 8px;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      outline: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

What I want is for the color of the text in active menu item to be green (#19D57E).

The active menu item is already displaying a green line at the bottom, but the text color of the menu item remains black like in the passive menu items. As you can see, I have specified the text of the color, but for some reason it is not doing it.

What am I doing wrong?

If you want to have a look at the website, please go to http://www.barrylong.tv/index.php/home

Thanks a lot!

Hector

Comment: i think you got mistaken about active and hover, use hover instead of active

Comment: @NishadNichoos This won't work, because `.active` is a class of the DOM element and furthermore hover means what happens on mouse over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the CSS needed:

```
.gf-menu.l1 > li.active a {
      color: #19D57E;
}
```

Note the `a` after `.active`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Lodder, Thank you. That worked beautifully. However, I now have a small issue: The dropdown menu items of the active menu have the same color as the background, so you can't see them. How can I keep the color of the active dropdown menu items in black (#555555) when passive and in white when hovered?

Comment: @Hectoritobh - you can use the following for css for that. Don't forget the !important bit after the colour `.gf-menu .dropdown ul li .item { color: #555555 !important; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes the menu items black again (when passive), but when hovered, they stay black. I had already some CSS to turn the menu items white when hovered but it appears that your CSS command overrules that: `.gf-menu li:hover,
.gf-menu li.active:hover {border: 1px solid #19D57E;background: #19D57E;color: #ffffff;padding-top: 1px;border-radius: 4px;}` What do you suggest i do?

Comment: Just to let you know: I removed the `!important` bit in the code you suggested because it was stopping the menu items to change color to white when hovered. I greatly appreciate your help. You rock! :)

Answer (score 0):

add this in your style sheet `.gf-menu > .active > a {
    color: #19D57E;
}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the color of the `.item` element in the `.active` li-element. At the moment you are trying to change the color of the li-element and not of the link.

```
.gf-menu.l1 > li.active .item {
    /* ... */
    color: #19D57E;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the CSS block: for `item101 active last`

Notice in your source for "home":

```
<li class="item101 active last">

<a class="item" href="/index.php/home">Home </a> </li>
```

You will see the text color property to change. The reason what you are doing isn't working is that you are changing the wrong CSS block properties.